# How do I convert a list into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, matrix

I have a list and a (2 by 2) array.

**I want to multiply the first two values of the list with this array 'k' shown below,**

(of course by converting these two values into a (2 by 1) array).

Then I want to do the same procedure with the next two values( i.e 2nd and 3rd values).

its like  [1,2] , then [2,3] ...[3,4]   [4,5] ...( these each couple of lists must be in 2 by 1 array so that I can further multiply it with *k* (2 by 2 array) mentioned below )

The array 'k' in all the cases is the same.

**How do I make this loop?**

```
my_List = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,9, 10, 11, 12, 13,14, 15, 16, 17 ,18 ,19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,27 ,28 ,29, 30, 31 ,32, 33, 34,35 ,36, 37, 38, 39]
```

```
E = 1
I = 1
l = 1

k = np.array(  [  [4*E*I/ l,       2*E*I/ l  ],
                  [2*E*I/ l,       4*E*I/ l  ] ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the solution you are looking for? If not add some expected output so that this can be edited accordingly.

```
import numpy as np

# Turn my_List into list of (2 by 1) arrays
twosArray = [np.array([my_List[i], my_List[i+1]]) for i in range(0, len(my_List)-1, 2]

# Multiply all (2 by 1) arrays by k
for array in twosArray:
    prod = k.dot(array) # you can collect prod into a list if you want to use it later
    print(prod)
```

Test:

```
# I'm using simpler values for my_List. You can test with your own values
my_List = [2,2,-1,-1]
# k is the same as the one in your problem
```

Outputs of print:

```
[12. 12.]

[-6. -6.]
```

Comment: If this is not what you want. Please shed more light on exactly what you want and I'll edit this answer accordingly

Comment: first two values of the list ([1,2]) then, next two values would be   [2,3] and then [3,4] and soo on.....

and.... when we multiply it with 'k', it must be in (2 by 1) format 2 rows and 1 column.

Comment: ok. I think I understand what you want now. I'm editing the code to reflect that. If that doesn't help, I'd advise you add expected output in your post to make the problem clearer.